# standalone not working with psfrag

Tags: texlive, mactex, standalone, psfrag

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

I use `latex` and `dvipdf`. I have two machines with MacTex-2016. I've just updated with `tlmgr` on machine A and the MWE produces a full A4 page. On machine B it produces a `pdf` the size of `text` (which is what I want). Here are the different lines in the log from machine A

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
File: dvips.def 2016/07/10 v3.1a Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
```

and from machine B

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> 
Package: graphics 2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
File: graphics.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration ) 
File: dvips.def 2015/12/30 v3.0k Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
```

How do I use `tlmgr` on machine A to downgrade `graphics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\usepackage[nosetpagesize]{graphics}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[nosetpagesize]{graphics}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

See also this bug report https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/25/pagesize-special-clipping

Comment: That fixes the current problem, thank you, +1. How do I downgrade a package when I know an update is causing trouble, so that I don't have to come here asking for a workaround?

Comment: Downgrading standalone wouldn't help. The problem is not due to a change of standalone, but due to changes in the latex core packages and standalone not adjusting to them. You could revert the updates of the graphics files with tlmgr but I wouldn't do it. The work-around is fine.

Comment: I wasn't talking about downgrading standalone. My original question (above) is "How do I use tlmgr on machine A to downgrade graphics?" The workaround is fine, but I want to know how to downgrade to avoid coming here for help on future bugs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question until the end. You find the documentation for restore here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#restore---backupdir-dir---all-pkg-rev. But restoring isn't always the best curse of action, also I don't know why you want to avoid to come here -- we are friendly people and quite a lot love to debug and resolve bugs.

Comment: Sorry: I did bury the question at the end. It is a friendly site, but this will be a worthless question when the bug is fixed. I thought downgrading would buy me some time until then. Also `\usepackage[nosetpagesize]{graphics}` doesn't work on my machine C with TeXLive-2015 "Unknown option nosetpagesize", so I need to maintain different .tex (or get around updating all the machines). I had a look at the manpage for tlmgr, but it seemed that `restore` was for when I'd made a backup. I can see now that some backups are made automatically, so thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: You can set the option as global option: `\documentclass[nosetpagesize]{standalone}` then you will get only a warning in TL15.